# Git Remote with Multiple Push URLs, Continue if Offline

Tags: git

I have a repo with multiple `pushurl` settings defined for a single remote:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    pushurl = ssh://user@system1.com/home/user/repo/source
    pushurl = ssh://user@system2.com/home/user/repo/source
    pushurl = ssh://user@system3.com/home/user/repo/source
    pushurl = ssh://user@system4.com/home/user/repo/source
    pushurl = ssh://user@system5.com/home/user/repo/source
```

Some of these systems, however, are frequently offline (user systems, not servers).  When Git encounters an offline system during a push, it stops and does not continue to the remaining `pushurl` addresses.

For example, if "System2" is offline, `git push` will stop even if Systems 3-5 are online.

Is there a way to force Git to continue down the list of `pushurl` addresses after it encounters a remote that is offline?

Comment: I doubt it's possible. Split URLs that are often offline into separate remote(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I did:

1. Split all systems into separate remotes (as recommended in comments)
2. Set default upstream to the system that's always available
3. Made this:

```
#!/bin/bash

remotes=(system1 system2 system3 system4 system5)

sysup() {
  { if [ -z "$1" ]; then local result=false
    elif ping -q -c1 "$1"; then local result=true
    else local result=false; fi
  } &> /dev/null
  echo $result
}

for system in "${remotes[@]}"; do
  printf "\n"
  echo "Now updating $system"
  if $(sysup "$system"); then
    git push "$system" master
    echo "Finished updating $system"
  else echo "$system is down, skipping"; fi
  printf "\n"
  sleep 1s
done

exit 0
```

Then I just `git push` whenever I need to update the "always on" system, and use the script when attempting to update all systems.